# How to adjust date to format “YYWW” ISO Week and ISO Year in Power Query?

Tags: date, powerquery

How to transform date e.g 03.02.23 to 2303 (4 digits number), where 2 first number indicate to year and 2 last numbers to week number.

In excel I use formula: =(RIGHT(YEAR(A1+26-ISOWEEKNUM(A1));2))&TEXT(ISOWEEKNUM(A1);"00").
But how to do it in powerquery?

Comment: How does `03.02.23` become 2303? If your date is really 3-Feb-2023, that would be week 5

Answer (score 2):

Try below, and see if that works for you

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

isoweek2 = (theDate as date) =>
//Ron Rosenfeld method 
let
a = Date.AddDays(theDate,-1),
b = Date.DayOfWeek(a,Day.Sunday),
c = Date.AddDays(theDate,-b + 3),
d2 = #date(Date.Year(c),1,3),
IWN  =  Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From(theDate)-Number.From(d2) + Date.DayOfWeek(d2)+6,7) in  IWN,


#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 
    Text.End(Text.From(Date.Year(Date.AddDays([Column1],26-isoweek2([Column1])))),2)
    &Text.PadStart(Text.From(isoweek2([Column1])),2,"0")
)
in  #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Alternate ISO week method

```
isoweek2 = (theDate as date) =>
// http://gorilla.bi/power-query/create-iso-week-and-iso-year/ Rick Rothstein
let IWN = Number.IntegerDivide(Number.Mod(Number.Mod(28*Number.Mod(Number.IntegerDivide((Number.From(theDate) + 692501) / 7, 1),20871 ) + 4383,146096),1461)/28,1)+1 in  IWN,
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds.

Comment: With your own work! Bonus points for me! I'm not usually an ISO kind of guy

Comment: If it hadn't been for his formula ...

Comment: Black-Scholes option pricing, Rosenfeld ISO, Poincaré conjecture....

Comment: Lol. Just wanted to say I have learnt so much from both of you - thank you. And congrats @horseyride for becoming the top all time answerer!

Comment: You weren't supposed to mention that !  Now Ron's going to answer more questions

Comment: Mari, did this solve your issue?